# autocomplete along with spellchecker and plural check for textfield

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, drupal-6, jquery-autocomplete

Hi I am using Drupal's 6 default jQuery autocomplete functionality for one of my custom textfield.

Now I would like to add **spellchecker** as well as the **plural check** as well.

**For example**

```
Word: Potatos

Spellchecker suggestions (including plural check): Potato, Potatoes
```

Is there any way to implement this feature so that when user type **Potatos**. Firstly spellchecker script will run which will suggest correct alternatives and once user selected proper word, the autocomplete script will run?

Comment: cfk editor or tinymce come to mind

Comment: @Dagon is it possible to add the same feature to textfield?

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is first install a server side solution for performing your spell checks, you could for example use [PSpell](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pspell.php). If your not able to install PSpell you could use Googlespell (just be sure to look at terms of use) There is also some client side implementations available (though not as reliable as a serverside solution).

There is a lot of plugins out there that will help you with spellchecking, but for your task Id go for something more lightweight like the [jQuery spellchecker](https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-spellchecker/wiki/Documentation).

Initiate your spellchecker with the desired options, and create an event listener for your textfield, a simple example would be:

```
var spellchecker = new $.SpellChecker('textarea', {
    lang: 'en',
    parser: 'text',
    webservice: {
       path: '../../webservices/php/SpellChecker.php',
       driver: 'pspell'
    },
    suggestBox: {
       position: 'above'
    }
});

$('textarea').keyup(function() {
        //you would probably want to add a timer looking to see if user is finished typing
        spellchecker.check();
    });
```

Then you would want to add a listener for the Spellchecker event `replace.word`:

```
spellchecker.on('replace.word', function() {
      //ie: submit the form
   });
```

If you want to do something more advanced, you could also try to override Drupals built in autocomplete `Drupal.jsAC` event `.keyup()` and see if the event `check.success` was fired (no incorrectly spelled words). If there are no misspelled words you use drupals autocompletion implementation for the onkeyup events. If there is misspelled words do nothing for these events.

```
var misspelledWord = false;
spellchecker.on('check.success', function() { misspelledWord = false; });
spellchecker.on('check.fail', function() { misspelledWord = true; });

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    Drupal.jsAC.prototype.onkeyup = function (input, e) {
      if(misspelledWord) {
          if (!e) {
          e = window.event;
        }
        switch (e.keyCode) {
          case 16: // shift
          case 17: // ctrl
          case 18: // alt
          case 20: // caps lock
          case 33: // page up
          case 34: // page down
          case 35: // end
          case 36: // home
          case 37: // left arrow
          case 38: // up arrow
          case 39: // right arrow
          case 40: // down arrow
            return true;

          case 9:  // tab
          case 13: // enter
          case 27: // esc
            this.hidePopup(e.keyCode);
            return true;

          default: // all other keys
            if (input.value.length > 0)
              this.populatePopup();
            else
              this.hidePopup(e.keyCode);
            return true;
        }
      }
    };
});
```

However it makes more sense to me to implement your own autocompletion by using jQuery´s AJAX functionality in spellcheckers replace.word event - you could also use/customize one of the jQuery autocomplete plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a spell check functionality to jQuery UI default autocomplete using the Levenshein distance algorithm. Check the code on github:

https://github.com/martintaleski/spellcheckAutocomplete

It is wrapped up as a jquery plugin. All you need to do is:

```
$('.your-selector').spellcheckAutocomplete();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution should be server-side called by ajax.

**option 1 - soundex mysql**

simple and quick

If you use mysql and your data language is english SOUNDEX could be an option for you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

Example:

```
mysql> select SOUNDEX('potato'), SOUNDEX('potatos'), SOUNDEX('potatoes');
+-------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
| SOUNDEX('potato') | SOUNDEX('potatos') | SOUNDEX('potatoes') |
+-------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
| P300              | P320               | P320                |
+-------------------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

Now, search into your database for words equal or with small differences based in soundex algorithm.

**option 2 - sphinxsearch**

Its harder to install, configure and learn but support multiple languages, stemming algoritms, advanced queries (boolean mode and so), improved performance...

If you want more advanced system a fulltext search engine with stemming support will help you a lot. Take a look to http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-morphology.

With stemming, when you search potato,potatos and potatoes search engine configured with morpohology=en will return you same results.